# Topographic correction in ENVI

Tags: envi, time-series

I work with LS8-data in a mountainous area where the illumination is poor especially in the winter months. My thought is to use either a shadow mask or apply topographic correction.

I will use all the available data for my research area over five years - aka apply a multi-temporal approach year-wise for a NDVI-time series.
Is there any way to implement e.g. the C-Correction in ENVI or what would be the best way to handle the topographic shadows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ENVI doesn't have topographic correction tool. You can do it as a secondary product using [ATCOR trough ENVI](https://www.rese-apps.com/pdf/atcor3_tutorial.pdf).

If you don't have license for that, I recommend you to correct your scenes via [QGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/saga/terrain_analysis_lighting/topographiccorrection.html) or [R](http://bleutner.github.io/RStoolbox/rstbx-docu/topCor.html).

Comment: Thank you! I am aware about the possibilites in QGIS and R. But would it be possible to implement my own algorithm using the gdal library if I want to use a different algorithm than the ones offered from QGIS/R?

Comment: Yes, you can. The basic form is with [`gdal_calc`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html). But, you can call all gdal tools in python and implement all kind of algorithms. This can be implement also inside QGIS/R environment